# Assigning $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, jquery, html, session

If I were to use the $_GET method to get an user's name, I encounter a problem if I have more than one user logged in. The newest user that logs in overrides the other user's information (not in the database) and if the previous user tries to talk their username will be the newest user's username.

Ex.
User Xp10d3 logs in. His username is still Xp10d3.
User IiBlurBeriI logs in. Xp10d3's username suddenly becomes IiBlurBeriI's username.

I know the reason for this, but I'm wondering if I were to assign a $_SESSION variable to the $_GET variable, will that variable stay static and not change? If not, how can I fix this problem?

login_check_update.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /* Sends an email to the user and adds the special key to another database */
    $username = $_GET['username']; /* Gets the username that was submitted in the HTML form. */
    $password = $_GET['password']; /* Gets the password that was submitted in the HTML form. */
    $servername = "localhost"; /* MySQL database. Change if needed! Most of the time its not localhost unless you're hosting on your computer. */
    $user = 'usernamelol'; /* MySQL username. Change if needed. */
    $pass = 'passwordlol'; /* MySQL password. Change if needed. */
    $dbname = 'vibemcform'; /* MySQL database name. Change if needed. */

    $bytes = random_bytes(10); /* Randomized code */
    $key = bin2hex($bytes); /* Makes the randomized code */

    $link = "live.php";

    $con = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname); /* Connects to the database */
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE (USERNAME = $username) AND password = $password");
    if (!$query || mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
        echo "Found data in the database! Visit the chat!";
        echo "<form action='live.php' method='post'><a href='".$link."'><input type='submit' name='btn1' value='$username'/></a></form>";
        echo "Session ID: ". session_id() . ". ";
    } else {
        echo "Username not found/password incorrect. Please try again!";
    }

    $conn = null;
    echo 'Username submitted: ' . $username . ' Password submitted: ' . $password . ' .'; exit;
?>
```

The following code isn't really relevant since I mostly copied it since I don't know how to make a live chat, but I understand 98% of it:
live.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['btn1'];

//Create a session of username and logging in the user to the chat room
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
}

//Unset session and logging out user from the chat room
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header('Location:logout.php');
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Chat Room</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='header'>
    <h1>
        SIMPLE CHAT ROOM
        <?php // Adding the logout link only for logged in users  ?>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
            <a class='logout' href="?logout">Logout</a>
        <?php } ?>
    </h1>

</div>

<div class='main'>
<?php //Check if the user is logged in or not ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
<div id='result'></div>
<div class='chatcontrols'>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return submitchat();">
    <input type='text' name='chat' id='chatbox' autocomplete="off" placeholder="ENTER CHAT HERE" />
    <input type='submit' name='send' id='send' class='btn btn-send' value='Send' />
    <input type='button' name='clear' class='btn btn-clear' id='clear' value='X' title="Clear Chat" />
</form>
<script>
// Javascript function to submit new chat entered by user
function submitchat(){
        if($('#chat').val()=='' || $('#chatbox').val()==' ') return false;
        $.ajax({
            url:'chat.php',
            data:{chat:$('#chatbox').val(),ajaxsend:true},
            method:'post',
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').html(data); // Get the chat records and add it to result div
                $('#chatbox').val(''); //Clear chat box after successful submition
                document.getElementById('result').scrollTop=document.getElementById('result').scrollHeight; // Bring the scrollbar to bottom of the chat resultbox in case of long chatbox
            }
        })
        return false;
};

// Function to continously check the some has submitted any new chat
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url:'chat.php',
            data:{ajaxget:true},
            method:'post',
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
    })
},1000);

// Function to chat history
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clear').click(function(){
        if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to clear chat?'))
            return false;
        $.ajax({
            url:'chat.php',
            data:{username:"<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>",ajaxclear:true},
            method:'post',
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        })
    })
})
</script>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class='userscreen'>
    <form method="post">
        <input type='text' class='input-user' placeholder="ENTER YOUR NAME HERE" name='username' />
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-user' value='START CHAT' />
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not be storing plaintext passwords in the database, you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. You should also be using prepared statements to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, each user session has its own `$_SESSION` variables, that's the whole point.

Comment: `if (!$query || mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)` < that contradicts itself. You also should be getting an error for your query. Those are most likely strings but you didn't quote the variables.

Comment: Yes; I know about the password_hash and such. I haven't gotten around to encrypting or hashing them into the database. And to answer your question @FunkFortyNiner I tried quoting $query but I kept getting an error. I believe it was the T_ENCASED_STRING one.

Comment: Also that didn't seem to work. It's still overriding all my variables.
Code: [code](https://sourceb.in/da5b7618b1)

Comment: nvm it works. tysm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SESSION[""] variables are global. I didn't know about it before, but I do now. I just assigned each variable for each user that signs up.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: blue;
        }
        #logout {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            max-width:1024px;;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logout">
        <?php
            session_start();
            /* Sends an email to the user and adds the special key to another database */
            $username = $_GET['username']; /* Gets the username that was submitted in the HTML form. */
            $password = $_GET['password']; /* Gets the password that was submitted in the HTML form. */
            $email = $_GET['email']; /* Gets the email that was submitted in the HTML form. */
            $servername = "localhost"; /* MySQL database. Change if needed! Most of the time its not localhost unless you're hosting on your computer. */
            $user = 'xxxx'; /* MySQL username. Change if needed. */
            $pass = 'xxxx'; /* MySQL password. Change if needed. */
            $dbname = 'vibemcform'; /* MySQL database name. Change if needed. */

            $bytes = random_bytes(10); /* Randomized code */
            $key = bin2hex($bytes); /* Makes the randomized code */

            $con = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname); /* Connects to the database */
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE USERNAME='".$username."'"); /* Gets the username that was submitted */
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $_SESSION['hash'] = $hash;
            $_SESSION['password_not'] = $password;
            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) { /* If the username exists... */
                    echo "ERROR: Username already exists. Please try signing up again.";
                    $con -> close();
                    exit;
            } else { /* If the username DOESN'T exist... */
                try {
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO dont (STR, USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL)
                    VALUES ('$key', '$username', '$hash', '$email')"; /* Insert all the data to the database */
                    $conn->exec($sql);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            $conn = null;
            $msg = "localhost/vibemcform/verify.php?str=". $key . " Please verify your email!";
            $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
            /*
            $headers = array("From: xp10d363@gmail.com",
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
            );
            */
            if (mail($email,"Verify your email",$msg/*, $headers*/)) {
                echo 'Message accepted to your email address! Check your email to verify your account.';
            } else {
                echo 'Message not sent to your email. Contact the owner of the website!';
            }
            exit;
        ?>

        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```